# How can I encode unsigned 16 and unsigned 32 bit integers to an unsigned 8 bit memory array?

Tags: arrays, integer, bit-manipulation, unsigned, bit

I know how to do bit shifting, but my values seem to run off the edge and I lose the original value in return of trying to preserve 8 bits.

Comment: This could very well be an interesting question but you're going to have to provide more information - e.g., sample code, sample input, and sample output that shows the problem. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unsigned 16-bit integer:

```
unsigned short val16 = 0x1234;
unsigned char enc[2];
enc[0] = val16 & 0xff;              // stores 0x34 to enc[0]
enc[1] = val16 >> 8 & 0xff;         // stores 0x12 to enc[1]
```

For unsigned 32-bit integer:

```
unsigned int val32 = 0x12345678;
unsigned char enc[4];
enc[0] = val32 & 0xff;              // stores 0x78 to enc[0]
enc[1] = val32 >> 8 & 0xff;         // stores 0x56 to enc[1]
enc[2] = val32 >> 16 & 0xff;        // stores 0x34 to enc[2]
enc[3] = val32 >> 24 & 0xff;        // stores 0x12 to enc[3]
```

---

**Updated**

Exactly same codes with decimal literals are:

```
unsigned short val16 = 4660;       // 4660 = 0x1234
unsigned char enc[2];
enc[0] = val16 & 255;
enc[1] = val16 >> 8 & 255;
```

and

```
unsigned int val32 = 305419896;    // 305419896 = 0x12345678
unsigned char enc[4];
enc[0] = val32 & 255;
enc[1] = val32 >> 8 & 255;
enc[2] = val32 >> 16 & 255;
enc[3] = val32 >> 24 & 255;
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to do this without using hex data type?

Comment: @bigdog225 Yes, of course. I've used hex-literals in the answer just to clarify the boundaries of each byte in a 2-byte or 4-byte value. You can use any other literal types, such as decimals.

Comment: how would I do that with decimals? if you don't mind showing me

Comment: @bigdog225 Updated to post.

Comment: appreciate it, that really helped